# Why is my numpy array of images one dimensional?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

```
train = []
#train_labels = []
files = glob.glob ("/datasets/mit-cbcl-farerec-database/test/*.pgm") # your image path
for myFile in files:
 image = cv2.imread (myFile)
 train.append (image) 
trainz = np.array(train)
print(trainz.ndim)
```

i tried different manners but they all resulted in one dimensional array

Comment: You are making an array from a list of arrays (images).  Most likely some of the images have a different size/shape.  For example some may be color (3 channel) and some may be bw (1 channel).  You could try `np.stack(train)` or `[i.shape for i in train]`.

Comment: so resizing the images in the array will do the trick ?